# Symfony 4 Command line send JSON string array

Tags: php, json, command-line, symfony4

Hi I lern PHP and Symfony. That I try do that pogram:

Command must take a string parameter containing array of products in JSON. It should return array of JSON string with products sorted by price ascending, and if price is the same sorted alphabetically ascending.
Sample JSON parameter:

````
```
[   
{
    "title": "H&M T-Shirt White",
    "price": 10.99,
    "inventory": 10
},
{
    "title": "Magento Enterprise License",
    "price": 1999.99,
    "inventory": 9999
},
{
    "title": "iPad 4 Mini",
    "price": 500.01,
    "inventory": 2
},
{
    "title": "iPad Pro",
    "price": 990.20,
    "inventory": 2
},
{
    "title": "Garmin Fenix 5",
    "price": 789.67,
    "inventory": 34
},
{
    "title": "Garmin Fenix 3 HR Sapphire Performer Bundle",
    "price": 789.67,
    "inventory": 12
}
]
```
````

The problem is that I can not enter the enters into the console.
I have not found a way to enter JSON objects into the console.
I tried to manually do this but the problem is that I get a badly shredded text later. This is due to ("") and ('').
e.g:

```
 php .\bin\console js_arr "{'title': 'H&M T-Shirt White', 'price': 
 10.99,'inventory': 10},{'title': 'Magent
 o Enterprise License','price':1999.99,'inventory': 9999}"
 array(1) {
 [0]=>
  string(136) "{'title': 'H&M T-Shirt White', 'price': 10.99,'inventory': 
 10},{'title': 'Magento Enterprise License','price':1999.99,'inventory': 
 9999}"
 }
```

I have good string sent to program but i need to manually change the quotes.

```
PS D:\comand> php .\bin\console js_arr '{"title": "H&M T-Shirt White", 
"price": 10.99,"inventory": 10},{"title": "Magent
o Enterprise License","price":1999.99,"inventory": 9999}'
array(5) {
[0]=>
string(11) "{title: H&M"
[1]=>
string(7) "T-Shirt"
[2]=>
string(50) "White, price: 10.99,inventory: 10},{title: Magento"
[3]=>
string(10) "Enterprise"
[4]=>
string(38) "License,price:1999.99,inventory: 9999}"
}
```

And this is bad example

Please, make suggestions and hints.

Comment: I wouldn't enter this type of text directly as a command line argument, instead, I would make your Symfony command take a path to the file, and then open, read and parse the file in PHP.

Comment: Thanks very very much. I try do this half day and now i reed it in 10 minutes :)
If you have more sugestins or hint please for it :D

Comment: @ILikeTacos File writing and reading is slow. With just 100k operations the time difference is considerable. Also handling concurrency is a bitch.

Answer (score 0):

**Either**

You pass your JSON with escaped Doublequotes

`php bin/console my:myCommand {\"foo\":\"bar\"}`

In your command class you will receive it as valid JSON `{"foo":"bar"}`.

And then parse it 
`$argument = json_decode($input->getArgument('myArgumentKey'), true);`

**OR**

Like suggested ILikeTacos, dont pass the json over the command, put it into a file, maybe in yml, then let your command read this file and parse the data.

For allowing more complex JSON structures and for more usability i prefer this solution, so you dont have to add the backslashes every time.

Comment: File operations are slow. Imagine 100k operations. Now imagine 5 times that number.
Escaping the double quotes indeed does the trick. 
But what about escaped double quotes in your string?

Comment: @vitoriodachef Good question, i tried it out, you have to escape the string escapes too `{\"foo\":\"b\\\"a\\\"r\"}`.